# Python equivalent of gdalbuildvrt

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

Is there a way to perform the same task as the gdalbuildvrt utility using GDAL Python bindings?  So far I have not found any way to do this other than creating a vrt of a single dataset and manually editing the xml.  I would like to create a vrt from multiple rasters (essentially performing a mosaic).  Is this possible using pure Python?  My other option is to use subprocess to simply call gdalbuildvrt.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note that as of 2021, [this answer below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314580/25916) is now the "offical" way to do this, and directly supported within the GDAL Python Bindings. It is no longer necessary to manually generate the VRT.**

Honestly it's easier to do this by using [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) in a [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) or [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

Should you wish to do this through Python it can be done. Using the standard dataset creation methods within GDAL Python we can easily create the base dataset [VRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html).

```py
from osgeo import gdal

drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("VRT")
vrt = drv.Create("test.vrt", x_size, y_size, 0)
```

Note that we are creating the dataset with no bands initially. From the documentation on [VRTs](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) that VRT datasets are one of the few dataset types that can accept `AddBand` arguments.

```py
vrt.AddBand(gdal.GDT_Float32)
band = vrt.GetRasterBand(1)
```

Now for each band we have to set the metadata items manually:

```py
simple_source = '<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">%s</SourceFilename>' % source_path + \
    '<SourceBand>%i</SourceBand>' % source_band + \
    '<SourceProperties RasterXSize="%i" RasterYSize="%i" DataType="Real" BlockXSize="%i" BlockYSize="%i"/>' % (x_size, y_size, x_block, y_block) + \
    '<SrcRect xOff="%i" yOff="%i" xSize="%i" ySize="%i"/>' % (x_offset, y_offset, x_source_size, y_source_size) + \
    '<DstRect xOff="%i" yOff="%i" xSize="%i" ySize="%i"/>' % (dest_x_offset, dest_y_offset, x_dest_size, y_dest_size)
band.SetMetadataItem("SimpleSource", simple_source)
band.SetMetadataItem("NoDataValue", -9999)
```

`SetMetadatItem` takes two arguments, the first a string of the metadata item, the second the item itself. This means that you can't subset a metadata item, so for data sources you have to set the entire contents as a string.

Note that we can use this method to create complex sources (`ComplexSource`) that contain look-up-tables of values, Kernel filter sources (`KernelFilteredSource`) of arbitrary sizes and shapes, and Mask Bands (`MaskBand`).

Comment: Thank you @om_henners - I ended up using subprocess to call gdalbuildvrt.  I am more experienced with Python rather than command line so I was hoping I could do this directly in Python, but its not worth the trouble of messing with creating XML strings as you described.  It's certainly good to know that I can do that if need in the future though.

Comment: Just found a use-case for having a python equivalent: adding unsupported features. For example the vrt file format supports an `overviews` element, but gdalbuildvrt doesn't use it. Thanks for providing a stub how this might be added in python.

Comment: @om_henners is there any way to drv.CreateCopy('path/to/file.vrt',input_ds) with absolute path to input_ds file in python? there is relativeToVRT="1" option, but how change it or set while createing VRT?

Answer (score 25):

The answer of [@rcoup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299218/131739) only worked for me, if modify it as follows:

```
from osgeo import gdal 

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
my_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT('my.vrt', ['one.tif', 'two.tif'], options=vrt_options)
my_vrt = None
```

Otherwise, the file is not written to disk.

Comment: JensL thanks! can you explain the intuition of my_vrt = None to write to disk? Just seems really odd

Comment: [@mmann1123](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/14610/mmann1123): Otherwise it didn't work and I had in mind that the [GDAL API Tutorial](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) said: "Note that the CreateCopy() method returns a writable dataset, and that it must be closed properly to complete writing and flushing the dataset to disk. In the Python case this occurs automatically when "dst_ds" goes out of scope."
SInce there is no `closing` for python, you have to bring your `vrt` out of scope, by assign it to `None`.

Comment: Actually, they just fixed this problem (see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Python-bindings-BuildOverviews-not-supported-for-VRT-dataset-td5429453.html)

Comment: I used `gdal.BuildVRT(dest_path, vsi_hrefs).FlushCache()` to force writing the file.

Answer (score 14):

Since GDAL 2.1 the CLI tools are available as library functions, and in fact that's what the CLI tools now call internally.

For example:

```
gdalbuildvrt -r cubic -addalpha my.vrt one.tif two.tif
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
from osgeo import gdal

vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', addAlpha=True)
gdal.BuildVRT('my.vrt', ['one.tif', 'two.tif'], options=vrt_options)
```

The [available CLI options](https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) directly map to the parameters of [BuildVRTOptions](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#BuildVRTOptions), plus there's some extras like progress callbacks available.

Comment: This appears to be for only certain CLI tools. For example, I'm trying to get gdaladdo to work but it doesn't show up. Same with gdalwarp. Do you know if they plan to support these as well? Would be very helpful .

Comment: @fpolig01 most of them are there - see `RegenerateOverviews()` and `Warp()` in the [API reference](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html). Arguments generally match the CLI commands.

Comment: @rccoup Thanks for the reply. Is RegenerateOverviews() the same as gdaladdo? Do you have an example of it working? I'm trying to do something similar to

gdaladdo -r average "D:\image.tif"

Comment: @fpolig01 [this post suggests `BuildOverviews()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949172/2662) (which is actually what I went searching for when I found `RegenerateOverviews`) — maybe give that a try?

Comment: For me two things were required to make `BuildVRT` work: 1. all paths (inputs and outputs) need to be resolved, 2. (in jupyter notebook) the result of `BuildVRT` needed to be assigned to a variable