# Automate band combination process

Tags: envi, multi-band

Everytime I get a new scene, I have to build a specific number of band combinations. It's almost 50 band combinations. I have to do it for almost every scene, over and over.

Is there any automatic process that allows me to build those band combinations automatically?

I am using ENVI+IDL 5.1

Comment: Could you also please edit your question to include what you have tried in IDL?

Comment: It is just a task of programming using IDL, please just do it.

Comment: @Aaron Can this task be done in Python and how?

Comment: Check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223920/8104