# Add bands' name and description to the Metadata when stacking using rasterio

Tags: landsat, metadata, rasterio, stack, gdalinfo

I'm using [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223910/using-rasterio-or-gdal-to-stack-multiple-bands-without-using-subprocess-commands?answertab=active#tab-top), of @Loïc Dutrieux, to stack 8 Landsat bands.

```py
with rasterio.open(final_list[0]) as src0:
   meta = src0.meta

with rasterio.open('stack.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
for id, layer in enumerate(final_list):
    with rasterio.open(layer) as src1:

        #the .astype(rasterio.int16) forces dtype to int16
        dst.write_band(id + 1, src1.read(1).astype(rasterio.int16))
```

When I open the `stack.tif` with `gdalinfo` I'm not getting bands' description in the `Metadata`:

```
...
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
...
Band 1 Block=3596x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-9999
Band 2 Block=3596x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
NoData Value=-9999
...
```

I would like something similar to this:

```
...
Metadata:
Band_1=Band 1 Reflectance
Band_2=Band 2 Reflectance
Band_3=Band 3 Reflectance
Band_4=Band 4 Reflectance
Band_5=Band 5 Reflectance
Band_6=Band 7 Reflectance
Band_7=Band 6 Temperature
Band_8=Fmask
Image Structure Metadata:
...
Band 1 Block=300x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
NoData Value=-9999
Band 2 Block=300x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
NoData Value=-9999
...
```

Answer (score 10):

If using rasterio >= 1.0, use the `dataset.set_band_description(self, bidx, value)` method and `dataset.descriptions` property.

```
Sets the description of a dataset band.
Parameters
----------
bidx : int
    Index of the band (starting with 1).
value: string
    A description of the band.
```

For example:

```
descriptions = [
    'Band 1 Reflectance', 
    'Band 2 Reflectance',
    'Band 3 Reflectance',
    'Band 4 Reflectance',
    'Band 5 Reflectance',
    'Band 7 Reflectance', 
    'Band 6 Temperature'
]
for id, layer in enumerate(final_list, start=1):
    with rasterio.open(layer) as src1:

        #the .astype(rasterio.int16) forces dtype to int16
        dst.write_band(id, src1.read(1).astype(rasterio.int16))

        # Assuming the source dataset band 1 has a description
        dst.set_band_description(id, src1.descriptions[0])

        # If not, you can put anything in you want
        dst.set_band_description(id, descriptions[id-1])
```

Comment: Thank you @Luke for your answer. My `rasterio.__version__ = '0.36.0'`. Properties like `src.descriptions` are not available in my version. if it's a matter of version, please help me to install the newest. Could find any guide in the web

Comment: Yes, not available in 0.36.  Rasterio 1.0a12 is available if using conda in the conda-forge dev channel - `conda install -c conda-forge/label/dev rasterio`. I can't help with any other installation as I only use conda.

Comment: If you can't upgrade rasterio, you can set the band descriptions with GDAL, but that's another question.  Also, look into the rasterio dataset tags property, but I don't have rasterio 0.36 to check.

Comment: Hi @Luke, I installed and used successfully Rasterio 1.0b1. The `dst.set_band_description(id+1 , src1.descriptions[0])` added the band description as following: `Band 1 Block=3596x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = band 2 surface reflectance
  NoData Value=-9999`. But couln't add info to metadata section. I guess it's due to `GTtiff` driver specification. I opened a new question about [masking and  staking at the same time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284650/stacking-and-masking-landsat-at-the-same-time-with-rasterio), please have a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mlateb Also have a look at the `update_tags` method http://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/tags.html