# Stacking Landsat images of different directories using Python

Tags: python, raster, landsat

I have different folders containing Landsat 8 bands. I want to stack them into a single raster file. ArcPy can not be downloaded. Is there any other way to do that?

I have this snippet for the code

```
import os, numpy as np, rasterio as rs, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, earthpy.spatial as es, earthpy.plot as ep
from glob import glob


landsat_path = glob(
    "/Users/admin/Downloads/LC08_L2SP_028030_20220628_20220706_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_028030_20220628_20220706_02_T1_SR_B[1-7].TIF"
)
sorted_path = sorted(landsat_path)
# print(sorted_path)
    
arr_st, meta = es.stack(sorted_path, nodata=-9999)
# print(arr_st[1])
ndvi = es.normalized_diff(arr_st[4], arr_st[3])
titles = ["Landsat 8 - Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)"]
ep.plot_bands(ndvi, cmap="RdYlGn", cols=1, title=titles, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```

But I want to run it in every folder.
Even if I get to stack them in a different folder I can try to run the NDVI generation.

Comment: In truth, ArcPy *can* be downloaded, as that's the only way for Esri customers to obtain ArcGIS media.

Comment: I have tried. But it is asking me to restart the kernel in jupyter which seems not working. thank you @Vince

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out how to stack the bands into a single image for a single path and row.
Many thanks to [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347415/earthpy-spatial-stack-function-and-data-type)

Here is the snippet:

```
import glob

# WRS-2 naming convention: path 28, row 30 = 02830)
wrs = ['028030']
#Local path for reference images 
refPath = '/Users/admin/Downloads/New_folder/landsat/'

for i in wrs:
    ''' Iteratively create datacubes by stacking bands within each acquistion scene folder''' 
    #check sub-directories (acquistions) under every WRS-scene
    subDirs = os.listdir(refPath)
    print(subDirs)
    for directory in subDirs:
        print(directory)
        #iterate subdirectories and compile datacubes within them 
        bandList = glob.glob(refPath +'/'+ directory + '/' + '*B[1-7].TIF')
        bandlist = sorted(bandList)
        print(bandlist)
        output = refPath + '/' + directory + '/'
        filename = directory + "_STACK.tif"
        array, raster = es.stack(bandList, out_path=output + filename, nodata = 0)
```