# BuildOverviews() not supported for VRT dataset

Tags: python, gdal, vrt, image-pyramids, gdaladdo

I am trying to build overviews in a VRT dataset with python GDAL.

I try this code:

```
out_vrt = os.path.join(out_dir, 'mosaic.vrt')
ds = gdal.BuildVRT(out_vrt, [raster1.tif, raster2.tif])
factors = [128, 256, 512]
gdal.SetConfigOption('COMPRESS_OVERVIEW', 'DEFLATE')
ds.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", factors)
```

, but I get this error:

```
ERROR 6: /home/umberto/Documents/jrc/FB_Data4Good/mosaic/test/vrt/mosaic.vrt: BuildOverviews() not supported for this dataset.
```

The VRT mosaic is created, but the overviews are not.

As far as I know, [`gdaladdo`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html) should work with VRTs, but I am not sure if [`gdal.BuildVRT()`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html#BuildOverviews) is actually using it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by looking at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314580/9518):

```
out_vrt = os.path.join(out_dir, 'mosaic.vrt')
ds = gdal.BuildVRT(out_vrt, [raster1.tif, raster2.tif])
ds = None # this did the trick!
ds = gdal.Open(out_vrt, 0)  # 0 = read-only, 1 = read-write. 
factors = [128, 256, 512]
gdal.SetConfigOption('COMPRESS_OVERVIEW', 'DEFLATE')
ds.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", factors)
```

Explanation (quoting one of the comments in the answer I mentioned):

> "Note that the CreateCopy() method returns a writable dataset, and
> that it must be closed properly to complete writing and flushing the
> dataset to disk. In the Python case this occurs automatically when
> "dst_ds" goes out of scope." SInce there is no closing for python, you
> have to bring your vrt out of scope, by assign it to None.

**BUG FIXED**

This was a bug that has been fixed (see 

[[gdal-dev] [Python bindings] BuildOverviews() not supported for VRT dataset](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Python-bindings-BuildOverviews-not-supported-for-VRT-dataset-td5429453.html) )